# Do vector indices not wrap around in C++? What is the workaround?

Tags: c++, vector, indexing

When I initialize a vector:

```
std::vector <int> someVec;
```

and I call:

```
std::cout << someVec[-1];
```

with an arbitrary number of elements, 0 is always returned.

Is there some way to get around this? The inability to do this in C++ is messing up my "sort" function. Is there any way to initialize said vector differently in order to return the last element in the vector, rather than 0 which seems to be the default. It seems that any index called outside the range of the vector will result in 0. It isn't wrapped which is baffling me.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined. It can return 0, 54564891, segmentation fault or [make demons fly out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). It's pointless to reason why this or that happens.

Comment: It's _undefined behavior_. Compile your program in debug mode to enable bounds checking.

Comment: *It isn't wrapped which is baffling me.* On what are you basing your assumption that indices wrap?

Comment: Python's negative "index wrapping" behavior is not standard in most languages.

Comment: When you use `[]` on a `vector`, it's 100% your responsibility to ensure the index is in range. There are other functions, (like [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at)) with different semantics. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: *"messing up my "sort" function"* - you're trying to fix the wrong problem. Use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with an appropriately crafted weak-order comparator.

Comment: This is not the droid (language) you are looking for.....

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of accessing the vector outside the bounds (such as at the index `[-1]`) is undefined.

> Is there anyway to [...] return the last element in the vector

Like this: `someVec.back()`

If you need a container that returns the last element when using the index `[-1]`, then vector is not the container for your purpose. The standard library has no such container.

> The inability to do this in C++ is messing up my "sort" function.

The ideal approach may be to fix the "sort" function to not require access to `[-1]`. The standard library comes with a sort function though, so you might not even need to implement one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to get around this?

To access the last element in a `std::vector` use `std::back`:

```
std::vector<int> vec(10,1);
std::cout << vec.back();    // prints 1
```

Note that after default initializing a vector

```
std::vector<int> vec2;
```

accessing any index via `operator[]` is undefined behaviour, because the size of the vector is `0`, there aren't any elements to access.